# call a javascript function from website link using swift

Tags: javascript, swift

I'm trying to load a specific javascript function I found inside a webpage using webkit.

but I don't know how to write this javascript (no experience at all using java)

i have the link to the page containing the js functions and I'm able to print out all the content inside. (it contain many java functions)

// this a fake link
http://203.178.105.133:9090/fly/static/js/flightInfo.js

the function I want to call is

```
function getSysDate() {
    $.ajax({
        url: ctx + "/common/date",
        data: "pattern=yyyy-MM-dd",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            /*$("#start").val(data.date);
            $("#end").val(data.date);*/
            $("#sFltDate").val(data.date);
            $("#eFltDate").val(data.date);
        }, error: function () {
            parent.layer.alert("Server Error.", {
                title:'Error',
                icon: 5,
                btn: ['Close']
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I tried with the following script but of course not work:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("http://203.178.105.133:9090/fly/static/js/flightInfo.js/getSysDate();", completionHandler: nil)
```

looking for a tips how to compose this script in order to run the function at that specific page.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not language-spam..

Comment: It’s not a language spam!! I just ask an help.. thanks.!

Comment: Listing `javascrirpt`, `java`, `html` and `swift` in the tags despite the fact that only `javascript` and `swift` are of importance **is** language-spam.

Comment: Despite having a similar name, Java is entirely unrelated to JavaScript.